# How to add a "model as an layer" in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

Is there any way to use a "pre-trained model as an layer" in a custom net?

Pseudocode:

```py
pretrained_model = torch.load('model')

class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):

        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.model_layer = pretrained_model # ?
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(num_classes_of_model_layer, 320)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(320, 160)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(160, num_classes)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = pretrained_model. # ?
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can absolutely use another model a part of your `Module`, as the other model is also a `Module`

Do:

```
self.model_layer = pretrained_model
```

and make inference as always with `x = self.model_layer(x)`

Comment: Are the layers of the model layer automatically locked?

Comment: What do you mean locked ?

Comment: Sorry, I dont know the exacts keywords but what I mean is are they "torch.no_grad()"ed ?

Comment: No, it will not be frozen automatically !